# What archetypes can be good for an Paladin/Oracle gestalt under E6 rules, or "Weird E6"?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, e6, gestalt

I am planning a gestalt Pathfinder character to be used under E6 gestalt rules, or, probably, under the "[Weird E6](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-5LkAkR2g9Nvi-mCOJ2cU1-xWF0zT_V-hlkcqhqG6NE/edit)" rules. I think about the Paladin/Oracle combo, as I have recently discovered a very interesting abuse while reading Oracle's Mysteries' descriptions: if you use *Life Link* Revelation from Life Mystery, you can redirect damage from your allies to you. If you use *Lay on Hands* to heal yourself, you only spend your Swift action on it, so  you can essentially heal the whole party with Swift actions, and your Standard actions are free for whatever you want. Plus, both classes depend on Charisma, so if I push it into the Sky, I get a double benefit. I plan to focus on healing the whole party with this abuse of gestalt power and probably also do something interesting on the front line: I will be a Paladin in shining plate, not an unarmored Wizard who has to always stay back, I have not decided yet what exactly.

However, the Oracle has, according to PFSRD, 16 archetypes, and the Paladin has 32. Are any of them useful for my main purpose -- healing the party while doing something cool?

Comment: As an aside, it isn't really an oversight or a new discovery; people have been playing Oradins (Oracle+Paladin) for a while as just multiclass characters. A few levels of oracle lets you get your party life linked.

Comment: I didn't vtc but I think the question suffers from 1. the combo you describe already lets you heal the party while doing something, and 2. every one of those 48 archetypes do "something cool."   So after removing the archetypes that actively thwart your plan by e.g. swapping out lay on hands, they all qualify as "cool" to someone even if only the designer that wrote them.  You'll need to get more specific than cool.

Comment: @mxyzplk I don't know about *all* of them counting as doing 'something cool', even if just in the minds of their creators.  I mean, [combat healer squire](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin/archetypes/paizo-paladin-archetypes/combat-healer-squire/)?